# Load data from API on app load, use data through user's session

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that I'm making on page load. The ajax returns a bunch of json from an API that I wrote.

This data is meant to be used as a base for a table on the website. I can alter the table and add rows to it based on the data from the API... however, what I'd really like to do is store this data (globally?) and use it while the user uses the page.

Subsets of the data should be able to be viewed based on what the user has filtered on some filters.

This is probably a very common use case... I'd like to not query my API every time the user filters something on the page, and I'd like to do it all on the client side.

I can manipulate the DOM, but it's just the pattern of storing the data and accessing it that I'm having issues with.

Comment: I see that simply doing `html = data` in the `success` handler of the ajax call is how to globally store it in my app. However, properly filtering it may worthy of another question on its own.

Comment: So you just want to cache your data client side? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage